# React & esLint: ошибка 'is missing in props validation'

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Код примерно такой:

```
const NameList = ({ names }) => {
  ...
```

Полный текст ошибки: *'names' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)*.

Почитал доку: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md но не понял, что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь `Prop-types` для `NamesList`. Для начала установи `prop-types`. Потом:

```
import { arrayOf, string } from 'prop-types';

// ...

NamesList.propTypes = {
    names: arrayOf(string),
};
```

Получается что-то вроде статической типизации для пропсов. В твоем случае names - массив строк.